# Alternative to SWITCH in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I've got a column in Table 1 called "Product Waste code". Each entry is either a number, or a string of text, or a combination of both (eg. 17003,1700*3, Not specified, 1700G). I'm needing to switch all these values to a string of text (eg. concrete, coal, tar etc.).

My current function looks like this:

```
Waste types = 
SWITCH(True(), 
[product_waste_code] = 170101,"Concrete", 
[product_waste_code]=170203,"Plastic",
[product_waste_code]="170301*", "Coal tar mixtures", 
[product_waste_code] = 170302, "Bituminous mixtures", 
[product_waste_code] = 200303, "Street cleaning residues", "Unknown")
```

However, Power BI returns the error, "comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type Integer". How can I work around this problem to switch out everything I need in these columns?

Thanks so much for your support!

Comment: Just compare with texts, not with numbers (i.e. instead of `[product_waste_code] = 170302` use `[product_waste_code] = "170302"`).

Comment: Thank you! That was stupid of me for not trying that. I appreciate the help!